# Swagger- Custom model in Request Header

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

My API requires two fields in request header (as Global Parameters). One input is Authorization field, string input and another input is custom User Object (Java POJO serialized as JSON). I have used following attributes to build Global parameters

```
ParameterBuilder authParameterBuilder = new ParameterBuilder();
    authParameterBuilder.name("Authorization") // name of header
            .modelRef(new ModelRef("string")).parameterType("header") // type - header
            .description("Bearer OAUTH_ACCESSTOKEN").required(true) // for compulsory
            .build();
    System.out.println(User.class.getTypeName());
    ParameterBuilder userParameterBuilder = new ParameterBuilder();
    userParameterBuilder.name("user") // name of header
            .modelRef(new ModelRef("User"))     // User model is not assigned
            .parameterType("header") // type - header
            .description("User object").required(true) // for compulsory
            .build();
```

I need to set model ref of second input to show as "User" model object in swagger UI, but it is not showing User model.

[image]

Please let me know how to configure custom POJO as input model for request header

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, though I didn't understand why you are passing an object in a *header*

```
 ParameterBuilder userParameterBuilder = new ParameterBuilder()
                                                        .type(new TypeResolver().resolve(User.class))
                                                        .name("user")
                                                        .modelRef(new ModelRef("User"))
                                                        .parameterType("header") // why not body?
                                                        .description("User object")
                                                        .required(true)
                                                        .build();
```